# How to stub a method that is called in initialize method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to stub a method that is called in initialize method.

There is a class `Company` like this:

```
class Company
  def initialize(code: code, driver: driver)
    @driver = driver
    @code = code
    navigate_to_search_result        
  end

  def navigate_to_search_result
    # do something
  end
end
```

And I want to stub the method `navigate_to_search_result`.

```
before(:each) do
  company = Company.new(code: 7220, driver: Selenium::WebDriver.for(:phantomjs))
  allow(company).to receive(:navigate_to_search_result){ true }  
end
```

But this code fails because `navigate_to_search_result` is already executed by initializing.

How can I stub method like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the following lines should be present/run in your test before you instantiate a `Company` object i.e. before you do `Company.new`.

```
allow_any_instance_of(Company).to receive(:navigate_to_search_result){ true }
```

or

```
allow_any_instance_of(Company).to receive(:navigate_to_search_result).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the `navigate_to_search_result` method out of the `initialize` method and call it manually. The `initialize` method is typically only used for setup.

Comment: Indeed, `#initialize` should not have side-effects, just set values on a new instance that will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
Company.stub(:new).and_return(Object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use doubles, like:

```
before
  company = double(Company, code: 7220, driver: Selenium::WebDriver.for(:phantomjs))
  allow(company).to receive(:navigate_to_search_result){ true } 
end
```

With doubles, you can fake an instance of Company without initialize it. So it will not try run `navigate_to_search_result` before you stub it.

But what are you testing? Maybe stub might not be the better choice, and you might test the method `navigate_to_search_result`